# Receiving file system events and notifications from HDFS

Tags: events, hadoop, notifications, filesystems, hdfs

Does HDFS provide a way to poll for file system events like file creation/modification/deletion? Also, does it provide/support any callback mechanism to get notified of such events as they occur?

I dont see an immediate and elaborate use case for such a thing but there is a specific requirement to check on this capability. I did not come across any documentation that mentions this. It would be great if any of the HDFS committers comment on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of hadoop 2.7, this is now possible with the `INotify` library. See this example: https://github.com/onefoursix/hdfs-inotify-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/onefoursix/HdfsINotifyExample.java

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no feature inbuilt `HDFS` that allows this.

Workarounds would be to perform client-side polling on watched directories, or a manual tailing of the transaction log(s) for all recorded events.